# Dynamically generating an entire page in a Javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic

I am generating this page inside a bookmarklet. (For reasons...)

I am getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` on line 10

(`var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;`) < line 10

At the moment I am simply copy and pasting all the code into the DOM to simulate the bookmarklet.

I would prefer to use pure Javascript and no Jquery.

This is my code:

```
javascript:(function(){
    function genRan(){
            /*
            Generate a random value of length determined by box 'input'
            Please note that this cannot be used for any type of cryptography however it 
            is fine for password generation. Do not use for public key crypto!
            */

            /* Get the value from input field */
            var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
            inputValue = parseInt(inputValue);

            var outputValue = '';
            var possibleValues = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

            /* Generate the random string */
            for(var x=0; x<inputValue; x++){
                var randomInt = Math.floor((Math.random() * possibleValues.length) + 1);
                console.log(randomInt);
                outputValue += possibleValues.charAt(randomInt);
            }

            document.getElementById('output').value = outputValue;
    }

    function decreaseCounter(){
        var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
        inputValue = parseInt(inputValue);
        inputValue--;
        document.getElementById('input').value = inputValue;
        genRan();
    }

    function increaseCounter(){
        var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
        inputValue = parseInt(inputValue);
        inputValue++;
        document.getElementById('input').value = inputValue;
        genRan();
    }

    /* EDIT 2: Make a document with body */
    document.open();
    document.write('<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>');
    /* document.close(); /* Not sure if this is needed right now */


    var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mainDiv.id = 'mainDiv';
    var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.id = 'innerDiv';

    /* EDIT: based on Dan's comment, I have added the following */
    mainDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    /* End of edit */

    var generateButton = document.createElement("button");
    var generateButtonText = document.createTextNode("Generate Random String");
    generateButton.appendChild(generateButtonText);
    generateButton.onclick = genRan();
    innerDiv.appendChild(generateButton);

    var minusButton = document.createElement("button");
    minusButtonText = document.createTextNode("-");
    minusButton.appendChild(minusButtonText);
    minusButton.onclick = decreaseCounter();
    innerDiv.appendChild(minusButton);

    var plusButton = document.createElement("button");
    plusButtonText = document.createTextNode("+");
    plusButton.appendChild(plusButtonText);
    plusButton.onclick = increaseCounter();
    innerDiv.appendChild(plusButton);

    var textInput = document.createElement("input");
    textInput.setAttribute("id", "input");
    textInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    textInput.setAttribute("value", "10");
    innerDiv.appendChild(textInput);

    var textOutput = document.createElement("input");
    textOutput.setAttribute("id", "output");
    textOutput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    innerDiv.appendChild(textOutput);

    genRan();/* Begin the program now */
})();
```

Edits:

Edit 1:
Append the div with inputs to the inner and main div

Edit 2:
Create document and body, then append to body

Comment: You haven't added `textInput` to the document as its parent never becomes a indirect child of the document, so when you do `document.getElementById('input')`, it returns `null`.

Comment: @DanD. I added some code above to add the `innerDiv` and `mainDiv` to the code, however I am now getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` for line 50: `document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);`

Comment: Well, looks like your document doesn’t have a body – which is not that surprising, since you justed opened it.

Comment: @CBroe, Thanks for that :)  I have added the body and tried to append the inputs to it. However I am getting my original error now where my ID `input` is null. From what I can tell, the inputs are appended to innerDiv, innerDiv appended to mainDiv and now mainDiv appended to a body that has been created.

Comment: Does setting the id via `textInput.id = "input";` instead of `setAttribute` make a difference by any chance? If not, you should already have a reference to the input field in `textInput` – can you use that to get the value inside your `genRan` function?

Comment: @CBroe, I changed `setAttribute` to `.id` and it made no difference. The only way I am getting the input value is via `var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;` Is there a better way for me to do this?

Comment: Did you try `textInput.value`?

Comment: @CBroe, I tried this and the same error for that line came up. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in how you are setting the `onclick` handlers. See these lines:

```
generateButton.onclick = genRan();
...
minusButton.onclick = decreaseCounter();
...
plusButton.onclick = increaseCounter();
```

Here you are actually calling the functions, and setting their return values to the `onclick` property, rather than setting the function as the callback. This is causing the functions to run before you create the elements, thus causing your error.

Replace those line with these, and your code works.

```
generateButton.onclick = genRan;
...
minusButton.onclick = decreaseCounter;
...
plusButton.onclick = increaseCounter;
```

#### Corrected Code:

```
javascript:(function(){
    function genRan(){
            /*
            Generate a random value of length determined by box 'input'
            Please note that this cannot be used for any type of cryptography however it 
            is fine for password generation. Do not use for public key crypto!
            */

            /* Get the value from input field */
            var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
            inputValue = parseInt(inputValue);

            var outputValue = '';
            var possibleValues = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789';

            /* Generate the random string */
            for(var x=0; x<inputValue; x++){
                var randomInt = Math.floor((Math.random() * possibleValues.length) + 1);
                console.log(randomInt);
                outputValue += possibleValues.charAt(randomInt);
            }

            document.getElementById('output').value = outputValue;
    }

    function decreaseCounter(){
        var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
        inputValue = parseInt(inputValue);
        inputValue--;
        document.getElementById('input').value = inputValue;
        genRan();
    }

    function increaseCounter(){
        var inputValue = document.getElementById('input').value;
        inputValue = parseInt(inputValue);
        inputValue++;
        document.getElementById('input').value = inputValue;
        genRan();
    }

    /* EDIT 2: Make a document with body */
    document.open();
    document.write('<html><head></head><body>Test</body></html>');
    /* document.close(); /* Not sure if this is needed right now */


    var mainDiv = document.createElement('div');
    mainDiv.id = 'mainDiv';
    var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
    innerDiv.id = 'innerDiv';

    /* EDIT: based on Dan's comment, I have added the following */
    mainDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
    document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
    /* End of edit */

    var generateButton = document.createElement("button");
    var generateButtonText = document.createTextNode("Generate Random String");
    generateButton.appendChild(generateButtonText);
    generateButton.onclick = genRan;
    innerDiv.appendChild(generateButton);

    var minusButton = document.createElement("button");
    minusButtonText = document.createTextNode("-");
    minusButton.appendChild(minusButtonText);
    minusButton.onclick = decreaseCounter;
    innerDiv.appendChild(minusButton);

    var plusButton = document.createElement("button");
    plusButtonText = document.createTextNode("+");
    plusButton.appendChild(plusButtonText);
    plusButton.onclick = increaseCounter;
    innerDiv.appendChild(plusButton);

    var textInput = document.createElement("input");
    textInput.setAttribute("id", "input");
    textInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    textInput.setAttribute("value", "10");
    innerDiv.appendChild(textInput);

    var textOutput = document.createElement("input");
    textOutput.setAttribute("id", "output");
    textOutput.setAttribute("type", "text");
    innerDiv.appendChild(textOutput);

    genRan();/* Begin the program now */
})();
```